# How to create or open a given number of files in fio?

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, ebpf

I would like to profile file_open() functions in the OS through bpftrace tools. I want to run fio workload for profiling. How to create/open a user specified number of files through fio read/write commands?
**Edit**:
The ssd has multiple partitions and each is a different filesystem on each partition. I am trying to measure and compare the filesystem overhead. I am using this command which inputs the path of the mounted path:

```
sudo fio --filename=/media/newport_0/1 --direct=1 --rw=read --bs=64k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --runtime=120 --numjobs=1280 --time_based --group_reporting --name=throughput-test-job --nrfiles=16
```

The issue is that the sample points in the results ie number of file opens is very less

```
@us:
[0, 1)               106 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@             |
[1, 2)               138 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@|
[2, 3)                11 |@@@@                                                |
[3, 4)                 6 |@@                                                  |
[4, 5)                 6 |@@                                                  |
[5, 6)                 5 |@                                                   |
[6, 7)                 1 |                                                    |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I ran the following command to find the latency of file_open function: ```` kprobe:ocfs2_file_open
{
        @start[tid] = nsecs;
}

kretprobe:ocfs2_file_open
/@start[tid]/
{
        $duration_us = (nsecs - @start[tid]) / 1000;
        @us = hist($duration_us);
        delete(@start[tid]);
}
````

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of reading and writing to files? There are many descriptions of how to do that in C on StackOverflow and on the wider web. For example, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm.

Comment: Please check the edits